# plupload pass values by upload url

Tags: javascript, php, html, plupload

I am using plupload as an image upload script. I want to be able to save images on one folder or another, depending on a selected option from a . Something similar to...

```
<select id="dir">
    <option value="dir1">Option1</option>
    <option value="dir2">Option2</option>
</select>
```

The code for initializing the pluploader contains the url for the upload script:

```
url : "upload.php",
```

I would like to be able to pass the option values to upload.php, so I can the handle them with $_GET, something like:

```
url : "upload.php?d=" + dir,
```

I have tried using:

```
var element = document.getElementById("dir").selectedIndex;
var dir = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[element].value;
```

The javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
// Initialize the widget when the DOM is ready
$(function() {

    // Setup html5 version
    $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
        // General settings
        runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
        url : "../upload.php",

        chunk_size : '1mb',
        rename : true,
        dragdrop: true,

        filters : {
            // Maximum file size
            max_file_size : '10mb',
            // Specify what files to browse for
            mime_types: [
                {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,jpeg,gif,png"}
            ]
        },

        // Resize images on clientside if we can
        resize: {
            width : 800,
            height : 800,
            quality : 90,
            crop: false // crop to exact dimensions
        },


        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url : '../js/Moxie.swf',

        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url : '../js/Moxie.xap'
    });
});
</script>
```

But it always gets the first option value as it is initialized on DOM ready...

How can I do this?

---

SOLVED with:

1) Add:

```
$(function() {
    $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({ //...
        multipart: true,
        multipart_params: { 'dir': '' }, //...
```

2) Add:

```
var uploader = $('#uploader').pluploadQueue();
    uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {

    var element = document.getElementById("dir").selectedIndex;
    var dir = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[element].value;

    uploader.settings.multipart_params.dir = dir;       
});
```

Source: http://williamjxj.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/jquery-plugin-plupload-for-multi-files-upload/

Comment: You should show the Javascript that makes the request.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have a way to test this, but it looks like you can [catch a `BeforeUpload` event](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2506-storing-per-file-multipart-params-in-the-plupload-queue.htm) and make changes there:

```
var uploader = $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
  // ...
});

uploader.bind("BeforeUpload", function() {
  var element = document.getElementById("dir").selectedIndex;
  var dir = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[element].value;
  uploader.settings.url = "upload.php?d=" + dir;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but cannot make it work like this... I get <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: dir in <b>/upload.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />

Comment: I didn’t include the calculation of `dir`, which you wrote yourself. But I’ve now updated the answer to include that calculation.

Comment: Yes, my answer to your comment was including exactly that hehe.Sorry I didn't make it clear!

Comment: I don’t understand the error, then. Have you tried printing out the `element` and `dir` variables to ensure they’re correct?

Comment: I updated my question with the answer. I could fix it in a similar manner following your guideline! So thanks!